# Copying an Array of Doubles and then Returning a Pointer to the Base

Tags: c

I've been presented with a task and am having difficulty completing it. Essentially I am to create a function that copies an array of doubles, allocating enough memory, and then returns a pointer to the base of the new array. I've tried various things but don't believe I've got things right yet...

This is what I have so far:

```
int *arrayCopyAndBase(double *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    int *arrayCopy;
    array_copy = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
         arrayCopy[i] = array[i];
    }
    return &arrayCopy;
}
```

Errors I'm sure are obvious but as a beginner I'm struggling to spot them. I know &arrayCopy should probably be &arrayCopy[0] but that results in an ever changing address. Any help appreciated; just needing to get on the right track.

Comment: `int *arrayCopy;` are you intentionally converting to an array of ints?

Comment: @Tushar Not intentionally, no. I had tried double but that just crashed the program.

Comment: Look at my answer and then feel free to change all those `int` back to `double`. Should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems:

You're using `sizeof(int)`. You're allocating an array of doubles. Ints are not the same thing as doubles.

`arrayCopy` is a pointer to an integer. This should be a pointer to a double

You are returning a pointer to a `int`. You should be returning a pointer to a `double`.

The return statement takes the adress of a pointer. You only need to return the value of the pointer.

You don't need the `for` loop. Using `memcpy` is much more sensible.

Comment: Made the changes as advised - thanks a bunch. However, the result is different each time the program is run. I'm assuming that shouldn't occur?

Comment: @JesterJeffrey When you say the result, do you mean the value returned by the function? Or the values in the array?

Comment: Value returned by the function. The test size and array I'm using remain the same.

Comment: The value returned by the function should be different each time it is called, because the value returned by `malloc` has no real meaning. It's just a way for the computer to remember where it is storing things. Also, if you like my answer consider voting for it or selecting it.

Comment: That makes sense! And I will, thank you. It was very much appreciated and provided the help I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is incorrect. Currently, you're returning a pointer to an array of ints (`int**`), when you actually want to return an array of ints (`int*`). I'm surprised your compiler wasn't complaining about this (or maybe it was, but you didn't mention it).

Try:

```
return arrayCopy;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use malloc, it returns a void pointer, you need to type cast it as a double.